# Smallest Covering Radius of a finite set

Tags: convex-optimization, computational-geometry

Let $X=\{x_{1},x_{2},\dots,x_{k}\}\subset R^2, \hspace{2pt} k>2$. The smallest covering radius of X is defined as

$$r^*(X)=argmin\{r:\exists x\in R^2 \hspace{2pt} \text{such that}\hspace{2pt} \|x_{j}-x\|\leq r \hspace{4pt}\text{for all} \hspace{3pt} j= 1,2,\dots,k\}$$ Using Helly's Theorem I want to compute the smallest covering radius for X efficiently, i.e. with computational complexity that grows polynomially in k. Also does the covering radius depend upon the norm used? (Here the definition involves $l_{2}$-norm)

Comment: This is just the [smallest enclosing circle problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest-circle_problem). And it is solvable (together with $x$) in linear time.

Comment: Yes I understand that. But I would like to specifically apply arguments involving Helly's Theorem to find a method to compute the smallest enclosing circle.

Comment: I also understand that there are methods available that are able to compute it in linear time. However I want a method based on the use of the Theorem. I expect the complexity would be of the order $O(k^3)$ or similar.